# How to use the django-admin-search with search_FieldNameHere ? I am unable to use the same

Tags: django, django-admin

The django-admin-search plugin version 0.3.5 has beem installed with django 3.0.5 on linux. How exactly to use the search_field query, I fail to understand. I am not great working with OOPS yet.
What I tried:

```
 def search_mfrom(request, field_value, param_values):
     """
     intercept query filter for description field
     """
     query = Q()
     #print(request, field_value, param_values, 'llllllllllllll')
     query = Q(mfrom='sowmiya@abc.com')
     print(query, 'qqqqqqqqqqqq')
     return query
```

The print(query, 'qqqqqqqqqqq')   never executes.  Am I passing in something wrong? The form field is **mfrom**.

Secondly, wish to send in login specific records in queryset **which this tool is overriding.** How to do that? I am able to override the queryset based on login domain part of the request.user, but since this tool is also overriding the queryset object of the modeladmin, I don't know how to go about. The code snippet for the same:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    domain_list = []
    temp = []
    qs = super(LogSearchFormAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    else:
        domain_list = Domain.objects.filter(
            customer__in=Customer.objects.filter(
                email=request.user.username)).values_list(
                    'name', flat=True)
        #print(list(domain_list))
        dom_names = list(domain_list)
        #print(dom_names)
        qs = MailLogs.objects.none()
        if dom_names:
            for d in dom_names:
                qs = MailLogs.objects.filter(
                    Q(mfrom__icontains=d)|Q(mto__icontains=d))
                
                # qs |= MailLogs.objects.filter(mfrom__icontains=d)

                # qs |=  MailLogs.objects.filter(mto__icontains=d)

                print(qs.query)
        #print(qs)
        return qs
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a mistake in the documentation for this case, I will update it coming soon.

I am not near my development laptop in this week, for this reasson I try to help you without testing code, sorry for this.

Another details is: I create this lib for Django 2, and in this pandemic a lot has happened, international change, visa details, search for house, new job, and more, it's crazy days. And I not have certain if works with Django 3. In next month I check this (I believe I will have solved everything)

But if works, all your need is:

1. Install a lib (check GitHub page)
2. Create your search form

```
from django.forms import Form
from django.forms import CharField

class YourFormSearch(Form):
    mfrom = CharField()  ## this type is just for registry will be ignored because your override this
```

3. Override in the admin

```
class YourAdmin(AdvancedSearchAdmin):
    def search_mfrom(self, field, field_value, form_field, request, param_values):
        """
            intercept mfrom filter and override
        """
        query = Q()
        # your Q logic here
        return query
```

Comment: I have implemented all what you have stated above and mailed to you after that only. The search form works no doubt, but wanted clarifications. Also note that the model admin page doesn't refresh after the search has completed. Looking forward for a complete solution on this tool at the earliest. Thank you.

Comment: Added the issues in github